# Was the Battlecruiser's Tactical Jump removed?

Tags: starcraft-2

I don't see the Tactical Jump option for my Battlecruisers, nor any place to research it (Starport,etc).

Has it been removed or am I missing something?

Comment: are you playing lotv multiplayer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it has not been removed from Legacy of the Void as of 14th January 2016.

There are a few reasons that you may not have access to the Battlecruisers' tactical jump.

---

The first is that you are not playing Legacy of the Void. Even if you have purchased and registered it you may have changed expansion levels to Hearty of the Swarm or Wings of Liberty; these two expansion levels will not have the tactical jump on battlecruisers.

You can change your expansion level by [following the below steps](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-expansion-level-setting):

1. Select Menu
2. Select Options
3. Select Gameplay
4. Select the expansion level from the dropdown box (Legacy of the Void in your case)

---

The other reason that you may not be seeing the tactical jump is that it is not available in the game mode that you are playing. Multiplayer is the only mode that you are guaranteed to have the tactical jump ability. Coop also has it but only if you are playing as Raynor.

---

So to sum up if you are not seeing the tactical jump ability on the battlecruiser, you are probably not playing Legacy of the Void multiplayer. Swap to this mode to get access to it.

Comment: Would it show up in LOTV multiplayer vs AI (a custom multiplayer game)

Comment: yes, it should.

Comment: Cool. It's like a new game, lots of little changes in LOTV. Thanks!